# Error Warning: mysqli::mysqli() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given in

Tags: php, mysqli

I am having this error on that 60 line in connection with mysqli. I've tried some modifica- tions but have not been successful.

> ERROR: Warning: mysqli::mysqli() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given in

```
<?php

    class KT_Connection {

        /**
         * The database name
         * @var string
         * @access private
         */
        var $databaseName = '';

        /**
         * The connection Resource ID
         * @var object ResourceID
         * @access private
         */
        var $connection = null;

        /**
         * Flag. what server model is.
         * @var string
         * @access private
         */
        var $servermodel = "mysql";

        /**
         * for ADODB compatibility
         * @var string
         * @access public
         */
        var $databaseType = "mysql";

        /**
         * The constructor
         * Sets the connection and the database name
         * @param object ResourceID &$connection
         * @param string $databasename
         * @access public
         */
        function KT_Connection(&$connection, $databasename) {
            $this->connection = &$connection;
            $this->databaseName = $databasename;
        }

        /**
         * Executes a SQL statement
         * @param string $sql
         * @return object unknown
         *         true on success
         *         response Resource ID if one is returned by the wrapper function
         * @access public
         */
        function Execute($sql) {
            if (!mysqli_select_db($this->databaseName, $this->connection)) {
                return false;
            }           
            $response = mysqli_query($sql, $this->connection);
            if (!is_resource($response)) {
                return $response;
            } else {
                $recordset = new KT_Recordset($response);
                return $recordset;
            }
        }

        /**
         * Executes a SQL statement
         * @param string $sql
         * @return mysql resource
         *         true on success
         *         response MYSQL Resource ID
         * @access public
         */
        function MySQL_Execute($sql) {
            if (!mysqli_select_db($this->databaseName, $this->connection)) {
                return false;
            }   
            $response = mysqli_query($sql, $this->connection);
            return $response;
        }

        /**
         * Gets the error message
         * @return string
         * @access public
         */
        function ErrorMsg() {
            return mysqli_error($this->connection);
        }

        /**
         * Gets the auto-generated inserted id (if any)
         * @return object unknown
         * @access public
         */
        function Insert_ID($table, $pKeyCol) {
            return mysqli_insert_id($this->connection);
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: you have your variables crossed for all db-related  code

Answer (score 1):

You have

```
$response = mysqli_query($sql, $this->connection);
```

I believe this needs to be

```
$response = mysqli_query($this->connection, $sql);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your connection establishing,

according to php manual [mysqli_select_db](http://php.net/mysqli_select_db)

```
bool mysqli_select_db ( mysqli $link , string $dbname )
```

> Parameters ¶
>
> link
>
> Procedural style only: A link identifier returned by mysqli_connect() or mysqli_init()  dbname
>
> The database name.

you have reversed the parameters which passed to mysqli_select_db function as follows :

```
mysqli_select_db($this->databaseName, $this->connection)
```

while it have to be as follow:

```
mysqli_select_db($this->connection, $this->databaseName)
```

Comment: Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in

Comment: this means that your connection to database ( [mysqli_connect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php) ) have not established , check out your connection

Comment: <?php

$hostname_Raio = "127.0.0.1";
$database_Raio = "u645954380_jaja2";
$username_Raio = "root";
$password_Raio = "";

$mysqli = new mysqli($hostname_Raio, $username_Raio, $password_Raio);
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Falha ao conectar: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}
else {
echo "OK";
}

?>

Comment: it's about how you pass your connection object to your `KT_Connection` class, update your question by more detailed code